# Compiling local jars in multiple modules with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Let us consider a scenario where I have a project `Starwars` which is made of three modules `Mission`, `Skywalker` and `Kenobi`. I have a jar file `force.jar` which is required by two of these modules. To achieve this, I place `force.jar` in `libs/` directory present in `Starwars` and I am use the following gradle configurations:

**build.gradle (Starwars)**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs "$rootProject.projectDir/libs"
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (Skywalker)**

```
dependencies {
    compile name: 'force'
}
```

**build.gradle (Kenobi)**

```
dependencies {
    provided name: 'force'
}
```

My main module `Mission` in turn depends on the previously defined modules. The gradle file for `Mission` looks like follows:

**build.gradle (Mission)**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Skywalker')
    compile project(':Kenobi')
}
```

Now, when I try to run `Mission`, I get the following error:

> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lforce/...;

Can someone please guide me towards how to configure these requirements in gradle. Thanks!

Comment: Why do the build.gradle of the kenobi and skywalker are different ? Could you provide a project on github which shows how to reproduce the problem ?